# Xsl & Silverlight: Using XSLT and an algorithm, how do I print out the entire Latin alphabet (a,b,c..z)?

Tags: silverlight, algorithm, xslt

I would like to have this:

Using XSLT, put each letter of the alphabet in its own grid cell.
The end result will be (result.xaml):

XAML Grid: 1 column, 26 rows. One row for each letter of the alphabet.

Perhaps there is an ASCII code way of doing this? I am not sure.

Thanks

Comment: Umm... what?  Why not just write out the final the xaml in full, why does this need doing programmatically at all?  Why use Xsl for this task?  Is this Javascript API version of Silverlight or do you have a Silverlight App?  What is it you are really trying to achieve?

Comment: XSLT is to be used for this task because it is for university. I don't have any application other than the XSLT logic. It is an XSLT file that will output a .xaml file. The input source XML file is 52000 elements with attributes and content. Each element's content is a 3 string combination (e.g. "= when it"). The application is supposed to be an A.I. app that takes input text and tries to find logic in it. Each letter of the alphabet occurs x times. This must be done as efficiently as possible. It is better to do it with an algorithm than hardcoding each letter. e.g. a = occurs 323 times

Comment: I just want an algorithm to loop through the alphabet and display each character in its own label/cell because it's programmatically more elegant than statically writing each letter of the alphabet one by one. I know that each character is represented in UTF-8 and it has its codes, so there must be some way to work with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recursive template `printAlphabetRows` in the following stylesheet iterates from 1 to 26 and uses `xsl:number` with the format option to print the corresponding letter in each iteration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="1.0">

   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">

      <Grid xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/avalon/2005" Width="400" Height="200"
            Background="LightBlue"> 
         <ColumnDefinition/>
         <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
         <xsl:call-template name="printAlphabetRows"/>
      </Grid>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template name="printAlphabetRows">
      <xsl:param name="letter" select="1"/>

      <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
         <xsl:number value="$letter" format="a"/>
      </TextBlock>

      <xsl:if test="$letter &lt; 26">
         <xsl:call-template name="printAlphabetRows">
            <xsl:with-param name="letter" select="$letter+1"/>
         </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:if>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

***Note:** I don't know anything about XAML Grids, so that XML structure may be off slightly (I googled for examples of XAML Grid), but it should be enough to see how the template could be used.*